# W3wp.exe is running high memory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, w3wp.exe

Our application is build using asp.net webservice (.asmx) we are facing memory leak with the iis 7 where the w3wp is consuming high memory arround 5 Gb. My question is how could we debug the application in production in order to recogniZe the leak of memory.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your Cache Options. ASP Caches all pages to memory unless set properly, Just a quick thought of what i have run into.

Comment: Use Task Manager to create a few process dump files and then open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com to consult Microsoft.